# Set the color of a table cell depending on the content

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I'm trying to write a VBA code in MS Word 2016 in order to fill cells containing a certain string (`"–"` in my case). I have tried something like this:

```
Sub CellsColorFill()
    Dim tTable As Table
    Dim cCell As Cell

    For Each tTable In ActiveDocument.Range.Tables
        For Each cCell In tTable.Range.Cells
            If cCell.Range = "-" Then
                Selection.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
                Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
                Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603923969
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Set oCell = Nothing
    Set tTable = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, for some reason, it has no effect when executed. How could this task be done?

Comment: Note that *"it doesn't work."* is a completely useless error description. Please describe what happens versus what you expected to happen. Or tell where you got stuck or errors.

Comment: The problem is that it has no effect when executed. I suspect that the condition in the if is not met, although I'm not sure why (I'm new to VBA).

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is because you are working with two unrelated objects, the `Selection` and `cCell`. Your code loops though the cells in the tables but applies changes, not to the cell, but to whatever was selected (or perhaps just the location of the insertion point) before the code was run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - It is good to have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to help you point out undeclared variable. `oCell` is not declared and I assume it's a typo of `cCell`

To check if a string contains a certain string, you can use `InStr` to check if returns a non-0 value (0 means not found)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CellsColorFill()
    Dim tTable As Table
    Dim cCell As Cell

    For Each tTable In ActiveDocument.Range.Tables
        For Each cCell In tTable.Range.Cells
            If InStr(cCell.Range.Text, "-") <> 0 Then
                cCell.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
                cCell.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
                cCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603923969
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly, it is just what I wanted to achieve!

Comment: @User1234321 - I forgot to mention 1 mistake that you made in the point and it was pointed out in Timothy's comment about `Selection` and `oCell`, please read his comment.